# How to check a string matched with multiple patterns?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, tornado

I want to check an URL in definition pattern list.
My pattern list is:

```
pat = ['/FoodListAdminCP/Login[/]?', '/FoodListAdminCP[/]?']
```

I used this code for check the URL matched with one item of this list

```
import re
f = re.compile('|'.join(pat))
if f.match(self.request.uri):
    self.login = True
else:
    self.login = False
```

Now, if I request `/FoodListAdminCP/Dashboard` as URL, that matched with pattern. Because start of this URL matched with `'/FoodListAdminCP[/]?'` who is in my list.

I want my request URL matched with entire of list item not part of that.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match the entire URL against your pattern, you can use '^' and '$' to match the beginning and the end of the string to match.

In your example you could use

```
f = re.compile('|'.join( '(^'+p+'$)' for p in pat ))
```

to get the regular expression

```
'(^/FoodListAdminCP/Login[/]?$)|(^/FoodListAdminCP[/]?$)'
```

from your `pat` list.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd rather not concatenate patterns, which may not be flexible enough, but match them separately, you can use `[re.compile(p).match(uri) for p in pat]` [list comprehrension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get a list of match results for all the patterns:

```
>>> import re

>>> pat = ['/FoodListAdminCP/Login[/]?', '/FoodListAdminCP[/]?']
>>> uri = '/FoodListAdminCP/Dashboard'

>>> match_results = [re.compile(p).match(uri) for p in pat]
>>> match_results
[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101c05d30>]
```

Then you can ask if all of the results are matches using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), which is what you want your `login` to be:

```
>>> login = all(match_results)
>>> login
False
```

Or in short:

```
login = all([re.compile(p).match(uri) for p in pat])
```

Comment: Or a generator expression, since `all` short-circuits.

Answer (score 1):

\Z at the end of your regex.

```
f = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(pat) + ')\Z')
```

Comment: You might want to add a '\A' at the beginning of the regex too, or something like '/xxxx/FoodListAdminCP/' might be matched.